# AFNetworking: how to get the response string in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

How to get the success and failure to get response string of server?

Basically I just want to call a function when success is true. The parameters are okay.

Here is my code:

```
manager.POST(urlString, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (requestOperation, response) -> Void in
        let result = NSString(data: response as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print(result)


        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["username" , "password"], forKey: "userDetailsArray")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        self.getHomeVC()



        }) { (requestOperation, NSError) -> Void in

            print("Error" + NSError.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your success closure should handle that.  Looks like it's called `(requestOperation, response)`.  Docs have changed but if I remember correctly there should be a value like `response.isSuccess` that you can use.

Something like this:

```
{(requestOperation, response, NSError) -> Void in
    let successValue = response.isSuccess
    if successValue {
    // call your success function
    }
    print("Error" + NSError.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. but when using response.isSuccess it is showing value of any object has no member isSuccess. Here is my code manager.POST(urlString, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (requestOperation, response) -> Void in  
            let successValue = response.isSuccess  
            if successValue {
                // call your success function
            }    
            }) { (requestOperation, NSError) -> Void in
                
                print("Error" + NSError.localizedDescription)
        }

Comment: this is the message which i want to handle {"success":false,"error":"Invalid username or password, try again"}

Answer (score 0):

You should find operation status in API response and check for "SUCCESS".

```
    if "SUCCESS" == Response.value(forKey: "operationStatus") as? String
           {
              // Do whatever you want on success
            }
               else
                  {
                     // If not success.
                   }
```

Hope this will help. Regards.

Comment: sir thanks for your help, but i have solved this issue.. right now i am stuck with the commentView section in tableView